# Django View Error - NoReverseMatch

Tags: python, django, django-views, view

I am new to django and I am trying to solve a `NoReverseMatch` issue. I think it has something to do with the views but i'm new to this.

The code is from a popular boiler plate repo from a few years ago. PLEASE NOTE: I tried reading like every answer on stack overflow already and have been stuck for hours.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

**main urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin


urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^login/', include('shopify_app.urls')),
    url(r'^', include('home.urls'), name='root_path'),
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

**urls.py inside of app**

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from shopify_app import views

urlpatterns = [
        url(r'^$', views.login, name='shopify_app_login'),
        url(r'^authenticate/$', views.authenticate, name='shopify_app_authenticate'),
        url(r'^finalize/$', views.finalize, name='shopify_app_finalize'),
        url(r'^logout/$', views.logout, name='shopify_app_logout'),
]
```

**views.py inside of  app**

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect, render
from django.contrib import messages
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from django.conf import settings
import shopify

def authenticate(request):

    shop = request.GET.get('shop')

    print('shop:', shop)

    if shop:
        scope = settings.SHOPIFY_API_SCOPE
        redirect_uri = request.build_absolute_uri(reverse('shopify_app.views.finalize'))
        permission_url = shopify.Session(shop.strip()).create_permission_url(scope, redirect_uri)
        return redirect(permission_url)

    return redirect(_return_address(request))



def finalize(request):
    shop_url = request.GET['shop']
    try:
        shopify_session = shopify.Session(shop_url)
        request.session['shopify'] = {
            "shop_url": shop_url,
            "access_token": shopify_session.request_token(request.REQUEST)
        }

    except Exception:
        messages.error(request, "Could not log in to Shopify store.")
        return redirect(reverse('shopify_app.views.login'))

    messages.info(request, "Logged in to shopify store.")

    response = redirect(_return_address(request))
    request.session.pop('return_to', None)
    return response
```

**Error**

```
NoReverseMatch at /login/authenticate/
    Reverse for 'shopify_app.views.finalize' not found. 'shopify_app.views.finalize' is not a valid view function or pattern name.
    Request Method: GET
    Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/login/authenticate/?csrfmiddlewaretoken=zEwwHeTfxK7apbAp3dSxsehsafxqjSgEM4t&shop=piepiedev.myshopify.com&commit=Install
    Django Version: 1.11.6
    Exception Type: NoReverseMatch
    Exception Value:    
    Reverse for 'shopify_app.views.finalize' not found. 'shopify_app.views.finalize' is not a valid view function or pattern name.
```

Source code / file structure-
https://github.com/Shopify/shopify_django_app

Similar issue but not working solution-
https://github.com/Shopify/shopify_django_app/issues/13

Comment: Can you edit views inside app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change inside authenticate(request):

```
redirect_uri = request.build_absolute_uri(reverse('shopify_app:shopify_app_finalize'))
```

Comment: Just tried. Im getting `'shopify_app' is not a registered namespace`

Do any of the views need modification? @Alexander Tyapkov

Comment: @NewPieGuy did you add shopify_app to your apps inside settings?

Comment: Hmm. If you're referring to root settings.py - yes it;s in there.

Comment: @NewPieGuy can you send the link to app repo? I cannot find it

Comment: I just added `url(r'^login/', include('shopify_app.urls', namespace="shopify_app")),` to root url.py and that seemed to do the trick.. Thank you!

will that break anything else moving forward?

and I cloned this repo -- https://github.com/aorzh/shopify_django_app

Comment: Great! I don't think so. If something happen just post question here.

Comment: that line broke login page so i took it out and am back to original issue :/

Comment: can you try to reverse it without namespace like reverse('shopify_app_finalize'))?